How can I avoid recursion in this JavaScript function that uses Promises?
I have a JavaScript function that generates an endless slideshow. The code works, but I'm concerned about each iteration ending in a recursive call to itself. Using developer tools, it appears that the call stack is growing.
I tried removing the recursive call to show_slides and wrapping the body of the function in a while (true) loop, but this caused the browser to lock up, burning lots of CPU and displaying nothing.
I assume I've missed waiting for the resolution of a Promise somewhere, and have tried appending .then(() => {}) to both the inner and the outer chains, without success.
Assuming that this is growing the stack (infinitely), rather than being treated as tail recursion and actually executing as a loop, what do I need to turn the body of the function into a loop?
Update: screenshot of Chrome dev tools call stack after a few iterations:



const duration = 2000; // time (msec) to display each slide
const sizes = [
  [4000, 500],
  [1000, 4000],
  [600, 400],
  [100, 200],
  [4000, 4000]
];
const sleep = ms => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));
let n = 0;

function show_slides(duration) {
  const my_parent = document.querySelector('#slide-div');
  let size_index = n++ % sizes.length;
  let w = sizes[size_index][0];
  let h = sizes[size_index][1];

  let my_randomizer = `https://placehold.co/${w}x${h}?text=${w}+x+${h}\npx`;
  fetch(my_randomizer)
    .then(my_response => my_response.blob())
    .then(my_blob => {
      let my_url = URL.createObjectURL(my_blob);
      sleep(duration)
        .then(() => {
          URL.revokeObjectURL(my_parent.querySelector('img').src);
          my_parent.querySelector('img').src = my_url;
          // A recursive call to iterate??
          show_slides(duration);
        });
    })
    .catch(my_error => console.error('Error: ', my_error));
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #dbd2c3;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  /* prevent body from displacing */
  margin: 0;
  /* body should perfectly superimpose the html */
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.outer-div {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
  /* Now create left/right margins */
  margin: 0 0;
}

.inner-fixed-div {
  margin-top: 0.5em;
}

.inner-remaining-div {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  /* hints the contents to not overflow */
  overflow: hidden;
}

.picture-div {
  /* force the div to fill the available space */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* center child elements */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.picture-div-img {
  max-width: calc(100% - 0.5em);
  /* included 0.5em * 2 margin on parent */
  max-height: calc(100% - 0.5em);
  /* included 2em margin on parent, may need adjust this further */
  border: 2px solid black;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<!-- Self-contained slideshow demo -->

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<body onload="show_slides(duration);">
  <div class="outer-div">
    <div class="inner-fixed-div">
      <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="inner-remaining-div">
      <div id="slide-div" class="picture-div">
        <!-- Placeholder <img> element for slides -->
        <img class="picture-div-img">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>




It's not really recursion if you call it from .then(), since that's asynchronous.

The while call is to fast and locks the screen. now if you could sleep 10 ms after each loop then you wont have an issue. now fetch operation could count as sleep and that is why it work as it is a promise

@Barmar recursion is a function calling itself. the timing doesn't matter

@ITgoldman …but there is no function calling itself. There's only a .then() callback function calling the show_slides function. And yet, we think about this as a (pseudo-)recursive approach, because the concept of recursion is the tool that lets us understand how the code behaves.

"I tried removing the recursive call to show_slides and wrapping the body of the function in a while (true) loop, but […] I assume I've missed waiting for the resolution of a Promise somewhere" - If you need any help with that, you'll need to post the code with the loop. As long as you had an await in the loop body, it should've worked.

"Using developer tools, it appears that the call stack is growing." - does it? Can you post a screenshot of what led you to this assumption? It should not grow the call stack (apart from maybe some clever devtools debugging utilities showing you an "async stack").

@ITgoldman, each then callback is called from a "virgin" call stack, being initiated by the engine when consuming the microtask queue. There is no function calling itself here -- no recursion.

I was talking by definition it's a recursion because show_slides calls show_slides (eventually). But I'll settle for a pseudo-recursive.

show_slides doesn't call show_slides. It returns after the call to fetch has returned a promise.

@Bergi - see update to OP

Your post still needs to explain why you think the call stack is growing, though: show_slides (which you should rename to showSlides: this is JS, not PHP or Python) runs every 2 seconds, so the console should "fill up" with messages, but the way the code is structured means that the stack won't grow: the function is not "kept open" while it resolves the next call. It exits just fine. (this code is effectively not recursive, but iterative, due to how async/promises work)

I inserted console.log statements immediately following the "pseudo-recursive" show_slides(), and the .catch(). Both are writing to log after each iteration, which would indicate that it's not truly recursing and never returning.

See Why does setTimeout() clutter my call stack under Chrome DevTools? – the Chrome developer tools automatically capture an asynchronous “stack trace” for debugging. Your code is correct, and the call stack isn’t actually growing. (I’m not sure exactly how the developer tools deal with infinite growth, but they probably truncate somewhere; a stack overflow would be a bug in the developer tools.)
Still, as long as you can rely on support for async/await, you can get both a cleaner debugging experience and cleaner code:


const duration = 2000; // time (msec) to display each slide
const sizes = [
  [4000, 500],
  [1000, 4000],
  [600, 400],
  [100, 200],
  [4000, 4000],
];
const sleep = ms => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));

async function show_slides(duration) {
  const my_img = document.querySelector('#slide-div img');
  let n = 0;

  while (true) {
    const size_index = n++ % sizes.length;
    const [w, h] = sizes[size_index];
  
    let my_randomizer = `https://placehold.co/${w}x${h}?text=${w}+x+${h}\npx`;
    try {
      const my_response = await fetch(my_randomizer);
      const my_blob = await my_response.blob();
      const my_url = URL.createObjectURL(my_blob);
      URL.revokeObjectURL(my_img.src);
      my_img.src = my_url;
    } catch (my_error) {
      console.error('Error: ', my_error);
      break;  // or continue after a delay
    }
    
    await sleep(duration);
  }
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #dbd2c3;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  /* prevent body from displacing */
  margin: 0;
  /* body should perfectly superimpose the html */
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.outer-div {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
  /* Now create left/right margins */
  margin: 0 0;
}

.inner-fixed-div {
  margin-top: 0.5em;
}

.inner-remaining-div {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  /* hints the contents to not overflow */
  overflow: hidden;
}

.picture-div {
  /* force the div to fill the available space */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* center child elements */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.picture-div-img {
  max-width: calc(100% - 0.5em);
  /* included 0.5em * 2 margin on parent */
  max-height: calc(100% - 0.5em);
  /* included 2em margin on parent, may need adjust this further */
  border: 2px solid black;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<!-- Self-contained slideshow demo -->

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<body onload="show_slides(duration);">
  <div class="outer-div">
    <div class="inner-fixed-div">
      <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="inner-remaining-div">
      <div id="slide-div" class="picture-div">
        <!-- Placeholder <img> element for slides -->
        <img class="picture-div-img">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>




Great answer. And I prefer your version of the algorithm to mine. I was lost in the strange (to me) syntax. Probably very advisable to avoid arrow notation until more experience with async stuff.

@Chap: For what it’s worth, I’d say understanding the idea of passing around and scheduling functions is more fundamental to learning JavaScript.

Sorry, don't get your gist. More fundamental than what?

@Chap: Than async/await.
